# Error: shutdown unexpectedly, Apache no arranca

Tags: apache

Estoy intentando conectar PHP con SQL Server 2019, Descargue los drivers (SQLSRV59.EXE)y los instale en Xammp y modifique el archivo: "php.ini" agregando las siguientes lineas:

- extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
- extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
- extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll
- extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll

Pero al intentar iniciar el apache me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No creo que sea un problema de puertos puesto que corri el Netstat y el puerto 80 y 443 no están siendo ocupados, además de que antes de agregar las 4 lineas el apache arranca sin problema, incluso con las primeras 2 (Archivos _ts):

- extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
- extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll

Pero cuando agrego las otras dos, me manda el error
Alguien podría ayudarme?

y al consultar la version del PHP:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]